# CSS - Content overlap problem with background colored element

Tags: css

I just encountered this issue, is there a solution for that?

[image]

```css
.wp-block-tll-blocks-aawp-block .rating-button {
  background-color: #ef970c;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 2;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.aawp-block-content-col-inner {
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="rating-button" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Check availability</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to your button to keep the text on the same line.

As OP suggested in an edit(partially correct), the `a` element can be replaced with a `button` tag (but not wrapped in an anchor element) which wont break the background. But even more important than layout, the `button` tag suits better the functionality for a rating, since there is no reference to other page, but an action triggered by the user. Hence, the proper use of a `button` tag instead of an anchor (`a`) tag.